# Setting a $scope variable in view does not work unless I call a function to do it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you have an html file where you toggle a boolean on click, sometimes i'm able to do it directly in the view and sometimes I have to create a function in my controller to toggle the boolean. Why does this work sometimes but not all the time?

Only works sometimes..

```
<div ng-click="myVar = !myVar">Toggle</div>
```

Always works..

```
<div ng-click="updateVar();">Toggle</div>
...
$scope.updateVar = function() {
  $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar;
};
```

Comment: looks just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g3u19wzd/1/

Comment: Can you supply an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce a simple test case for this yet. But i've come across it multiple times in the past and didn't know if it was a common mistake that I was making or what.

Comment: its really weird, I think you can reproduce the problem once you switch between different scopes, it looks like an angular error to me. I have the same issue

Answer (score -1):

If you have not set $scope.myVar initially, myVar and $scope.myVar are not the same variable.  Use...

```
<div ng-click="$scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar">
```

...to ensure you are always accessing the same variable.

Comment: Wrong. all scope vars are available in the view without the "$scope". It's basic angular knowledge.

Comment: Then why doesn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/g3u19wzd/4/) work, but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/g3u19wzd/3/) does?

Comment: Becase you never set `$scope.myVar` initially so if you perform a "not" operation on undefined, it's still undefined.

Comment: Do we know that the Poster has set $scope.myVar initially???  Not from the information we have, therefore, it is a valid answer to ensure that it works no matter the order of operations.  Updated answer to be more clear.

Comment: Your answer is still wrong. You're actually creating a new property on the scope called `$scope` with a `myVar` field inside. As @Catfish said, you don't use `$scope` in views because the view itself is already bound to the scope.